# File not found error when creating fedlet

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openam

I'm trying to create a fedlet using openam 13.0.0, but i got an error.
First, it complains that forgerock-util-3.0.1.jar was not found.
I renamed the file forgerock-util-3.0.2.jar to forgerock-util-3.0.1.jar and the next error was a file named webservices-extra-${webservices-extra.version}.jar with no content.

There is any way to generate a fedlet in this version of OpenAM?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in this version of OpenAM.
The bug was fixed in version 13.5.0

https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-8218